# Spring Cloud: Canary Deployments with Zuul

Tags: spring-cloud, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, canary-deployment

I am getting started with Spring Cloud using Eureka and Zuul and had some questions around structuring blue/green and Canary deployments. So far, I have the basics worked out and have Eureka, Zuul, and a config server working as expected. What I am trying to accomplish is set up a service that has two versions, say 1.0 and a 1.1. For a subset of specific users, I want to route them to the 1.1 version and everyone else should go to the 1.0 version.

The Zuul filter API is a little light on documentation and I'm struggling a bit to grok some of the concepts, so I thought I'd ask a few questions here. I have also have some basic filters running, which don't do a whole lot a the moment other than getting the identity of the principal and the service they are requesting. Where I am hitting a wall is understanding how to expose two different versions of the same service to Eureka and Zuul. A few things I'm curious about:

- Between documentation, posts, and other stack overflow, the term "service" and "cluster" seem to be used interchangeably. Is this correct?
- With that said if I have a service named `/simpleservice` do I expose two different serviceIDs (i.e. `simpleservice` and `simpleservice-1.1` )? And If I do that, when one of the targeted users requests `/simpleservice`, I'm having Zuul send them to `/simpleservice-1.1`
- Or, do you add another node to the existing service ID and add additional metadata to each node so that Zuul and distinguish versions 1.0 and 1.1?
- Is the correct answer "all of the above?" :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are using Ribbon as well, I would leave the service IDs as they are. Instead I would take a look at the [`com.netflix.loadbalancer`](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/tree/v2.1.1/ribbon-loadbalancer/src/main/java/com/netflix/loadbalancer) package. Canary deployments are essentially load balancing with very specific constraints. You could implement your own [`AbstractLoadBalancerRule`](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/blob/v2.1.1/ribbon-loadbalancer/src/main/java/com/netflix/loadbalancer/AbstractLoadBalancerRule.java) that picks servers based on some property you would like to base the routing on. Then add that rule to the configuration of your Zuul instance.

```
@Configuration
public class CanaryConfiguration {
    @Bean public IRule canaryDeploymentRule(IClientConfig config) {
      CanaryDeploymentRule rule = new CanaryDeploymentRule ();
      rule.initWithNiwsConfig(config);
      return rule;
    }
}
```

If you let your services register themselves in Eureka with different service IDs ("simpleservice" and "simpleservice-x.y"), I suppose things are bound to become complicated. You would have to extend the discovery client to ignore the version part ("-x.y", while still being able to deal with "foo-service") when retrieving the list of available servers from Eureka and then do some selection process to pick the right one anyway. So I guess things would just become more complex.

This is all based on best guesses, I haven't actually implemented this. I realize that this question is almost 4 months old. So if you have found some other solution in the meantime, it would be great if you could share it in an answer to your own question.

Comment: We were using Zuul with Ribbon, but I didn't think to look at the Ribbon project for the rule examples. This helps a lot. I'll post back once we dive in deeper.

Comment: @Ryan I'd be very interested to learn, how you solved your problem?

Comment: Have you dive in deeper @RyanJ.McDonough ?

Comment: I'm interested too. we will have 100 clients and I want to canary test with 10 specific, uniquely identifiable clients. Client app does not change, just internals of microservice. How do i configure the gateway(?) to route requests to the new version of the microservice for THESE 10 CLIENTS without changing anything in client